# Notification Message for Sending Emails

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am currently  building a form that sends a message to my email using [formspree.io](https://formspree.io/) api but i don't understand the js written. I essentially want to have it display the `#status` error or success message when the form is sent. The form works but the message isn't displaying

```html
<div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-content">
            <div class="close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <form action="https://formspree.io/f/xyylbnle" method="POST" id="contact-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full Name" required> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Send a message!" required></textarea> 
                </div>
                <button class="primary-button submit">
                    Send
                </button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
        <div id="status" class="success">
            Sent Successfully
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the javascript given to me from formspree

```js
 var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
    
    async function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var status = document.getElementById("my-form-status");
      var data = new FormData(event.target);
      fetch(event.target.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(response => {
        status.innerHTML = "Thanks for your submission!";
        form.reset()
      }).catch(error => {
        status.innerHTML = "Oops! There was a problem submitting your form"
      });
    }
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
```

This is what I edited to make the form work:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
    
    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      var status = document.getElementById("status");
      var data = new FormData(event.target);
      fetch(event.target.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(success => {
        status.classList.add('success')
        status.innerHTML = "Successfully Sent";
        form.reset()
      }).catch(error => {
        status.classList.add('error')
        status.innerHTML = "Error"
      });
    }
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
```

It's my first time using an API

Comment: It's unclear what's happening here. The JS looks fine but you need to include your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following lines:

```
var status = document.getElementById("my-form-status");
...
status.innerHTML = "Thanks for your submission!";
```

The code is expecting an element with the `id` of `#my-form-status`. It looks like you've written your status element holder with an `id` of only `#status` so that code won't find any elements that match and won't work as expected.

As an aside, I'm surprised the form is working as you say it is. The first line in the JS you posted is:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
```

but your form `id` is `#contact-form`. It seems like those should match.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. I said the code worked because I had already updated the JS so it expects my custom ids. However, I want the div with the id "status" to pop up when the form has been submitted.

Comment: @Isuckatprogrammingatm you should update the code to match exactly what you have. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example